# How to make a nested carousel in a flatlist that display some row of image

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

for a project, i have to make a carousel as the first element of a flatlist that display some image.

Here how it should look.

On the right, the result that i would like and on the left the result that i got :/

[image]

I try to hack into flatlist to render first the carousel but it push my 3 first image outside of the view as it is  a flatlist with 3 row.

If i render the carousel outside of the flatlist, the carousel do not move at all.

And if i nester it into a scrollview the flatlist don't load when it go down, you only have what you already render :/.

Any idea ?

Thanks all : D

Edit :

Ok so i hack it with giving a array with some empty object to my flatlist: [ {carousel} , {}, {}, ...rest_of_image]

This make it work, but it more like a hack and a ugly way to do it :/
If someone have another way, i be happy to try

Answer (score 1):

FlatList has property `ListHeaderComponent` you may put your carousel here, I guess it should help you https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#listheadercomponent